# How to mount volumes of multiple containers to a new container

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I created a mysql container and then I created a bookstack container with connection to MySQL base stored in first container by this instruction: https://hub.docker.com/r/solidnerd/bookstack/

Now i want to make a backup for volumes of these two containers. In all instructions described how to mount volumes of one container, but I see possibility to mount volumes of containers list in docker help:

```
$ docker run --help | grep volumes-from
      --volumes-from list              Mount volumes from the specified container(s)
```

So how can I mount all volumes of these two containers to new in single command without creating two containers "backup1" and "backup2"?

I tried:

```
# docker run --volumes-from competent_jackson bookstack_db -v $(pwd):/backup ubuntu bash -c <commands for backup>
Unable to find image 'bookstack_db:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for bookstack_db, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Comment: I found this instruction about dump MySQL base: https://gist.github.com/spalladino/6d981f7b33f6e0afe6bb

So my problem solved, but my question still has no answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using multiple containers, [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) be really handy as it ease the management of containers and volumes.

regardless, it depends on how you create and manage the docker volume. since you mentioned the option `--volumes-from` then checkout the detailed explanation on [docker backup, restore and migrate data volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#backup-restore-or-migrate-data-volumes)

and you can always use something like

```sh
$ docker run --rm  -v vol_id:/data -v $(pwd):/backup ubuntu tar cvf /backup/backup.tar /data
```

where `vol_id` listed in the output of `docker volume ls`